# Using your own fork of Next.js

Tags: npm, next.js

How would you use your own fork of Next.js in a project?

I tried using `patch-package` but the next package gets overridden by Vercel
Also tried releasing to npm but it's pretty difficult since it needs to release to many `@next/` packages first

How would you go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a project"? Locally in a repo? In production? If in production, deployed where and how (e.g. containerized in Docker, on Vercel using a source `git` repo, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Some people frown on this technique, but I've used it in many projects with great success.

> **tl;dr** - fork the repo on git and install directly from git. Works with monorepos by using [GitPkg](https://gitpkg.vercel.app/).

1. Fork the repository you want on git
2. Clone your new fork: `git clone https://github.com/<your-user-name>/<package-name>`
3. Make any changes and push those changes. Take note of the commit hash.
4. Install the dependency using the following format:

   ```
    npm install <your-user-name>/<package-name>#<commit-ish>
   ```

   - Important: replace the `<commit-ish>` with the hash from Step #3 (note: a tag or branch name works too). This step is important as it makes sure you are locked to a specific version.
   - If you are referencing a monorepo, you can specify the subdir for the particular package you want by using [GitPkg](https://gitpkg.vercel.app/).
5. Continue working like you normally would. As you make changes to the package, you will need to push those changes and repeat Steps #3-4 to get the new changes in your project.

---

#### Keeping things up-to-date

To update the package, you will need to merge any new "upstream" changes made by the original author and push those to your forked repository. Then repeat Step #4 above.

1. Add the original "upstream" remote:

   ```
    git add upstream https://github.com/vercel/next.js.git
   ```
2. Pull down any changes and merge them - make sure to reference the right branch name:

   ```
    git fetch upstream
    git checkout <main-branch>
    git merge upstream/<main-branch>
   ```
3. Resolve any merge conflicts and then push to your fork: `git push origin`
4. Repeat step #4 from above for installing the latest changes - make sure to pick a new commit hash or tag in order to get the latest changes.

Comment: Tried this too, but the actual next package is under `/packages/next`, so that doesn't work
Also when I tried to add `packages/next` in its own repo, didn't work too

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't know what `packages/next` is, but I've used this technique, even in monorepos, and it works well.

Comment: The actual `next` package that's released on npm is https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next

Comment: I updated my answer with the latest information I could find - you have to use a tool like GitPkg. Hope it helps you, though I've heard and experienced mixed outcomes with GitPkg.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help, but it doesn't work for the Next.js repo
The repo I wanna use is https://github.com/instatushq/next.js
GitPkg doesn't work, it produces an error, and can't publish to npm since it needs @next dependencies, which I can't publish to